# Publishing UWP App with Edge and Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, uwp, windows-store-apps, microsoft-edge

for a my UWP App I have created an extension for Edge and Chrome.
I have tried to create a new submission to the store but I have received the following errors:

- com.microsoft.edge.extension is a reserved extension type. Your app does not have permission to use this extension type. To request permission, please use our extension submission form: https://aka.ms/extension-request
- Your developer account doesn’t have permission to submit apps converted with the Desktop Bridge at this time. https://aka.ms/desktopbridgeforwindowsstore

I have fill the module at https://aka.ms/extension-request and at https://aka.ms/desktopbridgeforwindowsstore but, after 1 month, I didn't received any response.

Somebody know what I have to do in order to continue with the submission?
Does somebody have any experiences on that?

P.S.: I have sent a post at the MSDN forum and I have asked support at the Microsoft Answers but anybody was able to help me on that.

Thank you,

Regards,

MatVic

Comment: maybe open a support ticket here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support

Comment: I found this article in the blog [https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2017/09/29/microsoft-edge-extensions-one-year-later](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2017/09/29/microsoft-edge-extensions-one-year-later/#SD2htESbsQ5YWeEb.97). They are considering the most important Apps at the Store. The team is evaluating one extension at time... so I think that I have to wait some time :(

Comment: @MatVic `so I think that I have to wait some time` You're right. Currently they are prioritizing only the most popular extensions. They will relook at your extension at a future point in time.